# How do I store a timezone aware date using Diesel (Rust)?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I would like to store timezone-aware dates in Postgres, but I am struggling figure out how to do so. I have included the `chrono` feature for `diesel` in my `cargo.toml`.

Here is the relevant portion of my `schema.rs`:

```
table! {
    budgets (id) {
        id -> Uuid,
        is_shared -> Bool,
        is_private -> Bool,
        is_deleted -> Bool,
        name -> Varchar,
        description -> Nullable<Text>,
        start_date -> Timestamptz,
        end_date -> Timestamptz,
        latest_entry_time -> Timestamp,
        modified_timestamp -> Timestamp,
        created_timestamp -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

And my model:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Associations, Identifiable, Queryable, QueryableByName)]
#[table_name = "budgets"]
pub struct Budget {
    pub id: uuid::Uuid,
    pub is_shared: bool,
    pub is_private: bool,
    pub is_deleted: bool,

    pub name: String,
    pub description: Option<String>,

    pub start_date: DateTime<FixedOffset>,
    pub end_date: DateTime<FixedOffset>,
    pub latest_entry_time: NaiveDateTime,

    pub modified_timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
    pub created_timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
}

#[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
#[table_name = "budgets"]
pub struct NewBudget<'a> {
    pub id: uuid::Uuid,
    pub is_shared: bool,
    pub is_private: bool,
    pub is_deleted: bool,

    pub name: &'a str,
    pub description: Option<&'a str>,

    pub start_date: DateTime<FixedOffset>,
    pub end_date: DateTime<FixedOffset>,
    pub latest_entry_time: NaiveDateTime,

    pub modified_timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
    pub created_timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
}
```

When I try to build, I get this error when I try to use the model:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `chrono::DateTime<chrono::FixedOffset>: FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/utils/db/budget.rs:20:42
     |
20   |     let budget = budgets.find(budget_id).first::<Budget>(db_connection)?;
     |                                          ^^^^^ the trait `FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, Pg>` is not implemented for `chrono::DateTime<chrono::FixedOffset>`
     |
     = help: the following implementations were found:
               <chrono::DateTime<Utc> as FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, Pg>>
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, Pg>` for `chrono::DateTime<chrono::FixedOffset>`
     = note: 2 redundant requirements hidden
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp), Pg>` for `Budget`
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<_, Budget>` for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<budgets::table, query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause, query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<budgets::columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, &uuid::Uuid>>>, query_builder::order_clause::NoOrderClause, query_builder::limit_clause::LimitClause<diesel::expression::bound::Bound<BigInt, i64>>>`
note: required by a bound in `first`
    --> /Users/tanner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-1.4.8/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1343:22
     |
1343 |         Limit<Self>: LoadQuery<Conn, U>,
     |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `first`
```

Here is the function that the error refers to:

```
pub fn get_budget_by_id(
    db_connection: &DbConnection,
    budget_id: &Uuid,
) -> Result<OutputBudget, diesel::result::Error> {
    let budget = budgets.find(budget_id).first::<Budget>(db_connection)?;

    let loaded_categories = Category::belonging_to(&budget).load::<Category>(db_connection)?;

    let output_budget = OutputBudget {
        id: budget.id,
        is_shared: budget.is_shared,
        is_private: budget.is_private,
        is_deleted: budget.is_deleted,
        name: budget.name,
        description: budget.description,
        categories: loaded_categories,
        start_date: budget.start_date,
        end_date: budget.end_date,
        latest_entry_time: budget.latest_entry_time,
        modified_timestamp: budget.modified_timestamp,
        created_timestamp: budget.created_timestamp,
    };

    Ok(output_budget)
}
```

I would like to be able to store timestamps from multiple timezones. Can I only use `chrono::DateTime<Utc>` or am I missing something?

Comment: I have a similar problem, thanks for this question. If I manage to figure it out I'll post the answer

Comment: latest_entry_time -> Timestamp, is not compatible with Rust i64. I manage to solve this by changing Timestamp to BIGINT which produces a Int8 on the table! macro. This will allow you to use `let unix_time: i64 = Utc::now().timestamp();` which can be inserted. It's not the perfect solution, but it's working for me now, just let postgres handle the data insert while rust handles the objects (hence, postgres does not inserts the timestamp automatically)

Comment: Actually, that's not a bad solution: You are always storing UTC date/times. Your front en layer should be able to show them in the right time zone.